# Exclude NULL Columns in Results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My query below returns these results

[image]

```
SELECT 
     BorrowerNumber
     ,CASE WHEN [Score_CorrectID_Accuracy] = 'Error' THEN 'Error' END AS [Correct ID]
     ,CASE WHEN [Score_ProperlyIdentified_Accuracy] = 'Error' THEN 'Error' END AS [PCA Identified Itself]
     ,CASE [Score_Tone_Accuracy] WHEN 'Error' THEN 'Error' END AS [Score_Tone_Accuracy]
     ,CASE [Score_Accuracy_Accuracy] WHEN 'Error' THEN 'Error' END AS [Score_Accuracy_Accuracy]
     ,CASE [Score_Notepad_Accuracy] WHEN 'Error' THEN 'Error' END AS [Score_Notepad_Accuracy] 
    FROM 
        Reviews INNER JOIN QCTier1 ON Reviews.ReviewID = QCTier1.ReviewID
```

These are the results I'm looking to achieve where the last column is not in the results because it has a NULL value. Thanks

[image: Desired results]

Comment: If you don't want the column don't select it then.

Comment: but I want the column in the results if it has a value

Comment: Please provide more details on what you are trying to accomplish. Nothing about your query suggests that it cannot return multiple rows. What would you expect to happen if some rows had a NULL value in the last column and some rows did not?

Comment: Hello, Yes, the query will possibly return multiple rows.  I have around 20 columns although I'm only showing 5 to simplify it as an example, and I only want to show those columns in the results that have at least one non-null value. The result will be used in a report and I want only the columns where an error was made.  If the column has no 'Error' values, then I don't want the column in the results. Thanks

Comment: That makes for over a million (2^20) possible result set structures. I'm not sure how your report will handle that, but surely it would be easier to deal with nulls.

Comment: I have to ask, what reporting tool are you using? Every tool I've ever used will throw a fit if you have fields in the report linked to fields in the dataset that do not exist. How will you set those columns up? If my third column is a textbox linked to the query's "Score Tone Accuracy" field, and the query does not return that field in the result set, the report will not render. This is true for every tool I've used. As others have said, just handle the NULL values in the report itself. You can aggregate the results inside the report, or in the query, and use that value to show or hide cols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to exclude the columns themselves from the result set without using some really wacky and difficult code. But what you can do (in pretty much every reporting tool) is show or hide columns in your report based on a formula or even a single value.

So take your existing query, and for each column that you may want to hide, add another column that aggregates your "hide column" over the whole dataset.

```
SELECT 
    sq.*,
    max(sq.[Correct ID]) as MAX_CORRECT_ID,
    max(sq.[PCA Identified Itself]) as MAX_PCA_ID_SELF
    -- ... rinse and repeat
FROM (
    SELECT 
         BorrowerNumber
         ,CASE WHEN [Score_CorrectID_Accuracy] = 'Error' THEN 'Error' END AS [Correct ID]
         ,CASE WHEN [Score_ProperlyIdentified_Accuracy] = 'Error' THEN 'Error' END AS [PCA Identified Itself]
         ,CASE [Score_Tone_Accuracy] WHEN 'Error' THEN 'Error' END AS [Score_Tone_Accuracy]
         ,CASE [Score_Accuracy_Accuracy] WHEN 'Error' THEN 'Error' END AS [Score_Accuracy_Accuracy]
         ,CASE [Score_Notepad_Accuracy] WHEN 'Error' THEN 'Error' END AS [Score_Notepad_Accuracy] 
        FROM 
            Reviews INNER JOIN QCTier1 ON Reviews.ReviewID = QCTier1.ReviewID
) sq
```

Anytime the MAX column is null in the first row, you can be sure there were no non-null values in the corresponding column.

In my opinion for a result set that typically returns only a few rows, this is a monumental waste of time since you could just use a simple aggregation or formula in your reporting tool to conditionally hide the columns, and keep your SQL clean. If you had hundreds of thousands of rows in the data set, or if you had more complex requirements requiring grouping or windowing or both, then this could possibly be worthwhile. For example, sometimes it's useful to show aggregate data for all rows sharing a specific attribute with the current row, without grouping the whole report by that column.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know standard tsql is not able to display/hide a column based on value.

You can implement this in your further programs/UI , if you are programming.

There is another interesting approach to solve this with iff and pivoting here in stackoverflow, but thats way too complicated for this business need!

Maybe you should try to implement this feature in your report program, not in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @COUNT int

SELECT @COUNT = COUNT(*)
FROM Reviews INNER JOIN QCTier1 ON Reviews.ReviewID = QCTier1.ReviewID
WHERE Score_Notepad_Accuracy IS NOT NULL

IF @COUNT = 0 THEN
    SELECT 
       BorrowerNumber
      ,CASE WHEN [Score_CorrectID_Accuracy] = 'Error' THEN 'Error' END AS [Correct ID]
      ,CASE WHEN [Score_ProperlyIdentified_Accuracy] = 'Error' THEN 'Error' END AS [PCA Identified Itself]
      ,CASE [Score_Tone_Accuracy] WHEN 'Error' THEN 'Error' END AS [Score_Tone_Accuracy]
      ,CASE [Score_Accuracy_Accuracy] WHEN 'Error' THEN 'Error' END AS [Score_Accuracy_Accuracy]
    FROM 
       Reviews INNER JOIN QCTier1 ON Reviews.ReviewID = QCTier1.ReviewID
ELSE
    SELECT 
       BorrowerNumber
      ,CASE WHEN [Score_CorrectID_Accuracy] = 'Error' THEN 'Error' END AS [Correct ID]
      ,CASE WHEN [Score_ProperlyIdentified_Accuracy] = 'Error' THEN 'Error' END AS [PCA Identified Itself]
      ,CASE [Score_Tone_Accuracy] WHEN 'Error' THEN 'Error' END AS [Score_Tone_Accuracy]
      ,CASE [Score_Accuracy_Accuracy] WHEN 'Error' THEN 'Error' END AS [Score_Accuracy_Accuracy]
    FROM 
       Reviews INNER JOIN QCTier1 ON Reviews.ReviewID = QCTier1.ReviewID
```

Personally I would never do it this way.  You should hide the column in the reporting program, not in the data source.